# Google Cloud Pub/Sub ack v nack

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I know that `message.ack()` acknowledges a message, to prevent it being re-sent when the acknowledgement deadline has passed.

But what does `message.nack()` do? What is the difference between ack and nack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.nack()` (that is language specific, I know not all languages use that syntax) tells Cloud Pub/Sub that this particular client cannot handle the message.  The service can then send the message to another client, potentially after some backoff, where it (hopefully) will be handled successfully.